# Enabling Smart Identification for an Object

Tags: object, repository, qtp, identification

How do I enable Smart Identification for an Object?

It was added to OR with SI enabled but I am not sure why it got set to FALSE. How do I set it back to TRUE for this Object?

Answer (score 0):

Smart identification basically has two phases.

1. When the test object is created (via record or learn) if SI is enabled all the properties needed for identification are captured
2. When a test is run, if SI is enabled the properties captured may be used if the regular properties aren't good enough.

One of the implications of this is that the SI settings that were active when the object was created impact the identification during run. If you change the set of properties, the original properties are still used. Since in your case no smart identification properties were captured the *Enable Smart Identification* option is disabled for this object.

### tl;dr;

The solution to your problem is to enable SI for you object and then run the test in **Update Run Mode** (be sure to check the **Update test object description** checkbox).

Comment: Thanks for these info but I am actually using Object Spy(Update Run Mode didnt help or may be I am not using it correctly) to add the Objects and am working on a PeopleSoft application and the issue is only with PSFrame(PeopleSoftFrame). 

After I add the object to my Local OR, the PSFrame shows SI to be set as "True" but then it's set into "False". Your comment does specify why as stated below
"Since in your case no smart identification properties were captured the Enable Smart Identification option is disabled for this object."
Contd.....

Comment: However what I dont understand is the failure of object identification without the SI being enabled when there were no SI properties captured

Currently have a work around to copy the Objects directly into the page level(Eliminating PSFrame level) and it's working fine so far but would like to know why something like this would happen?

Comment: @EnthusiasticLearner, identification shouldn't fail just because SI is disabled. I see that PSFrame has SI disabled by default and no properties defined for SI (again by default). In short I'm not sure I understand your question. Please clarify.

Comment: For the PSFrame which I added into OR, the SI was enabled when I added. I thought it was getting disabled eventually(when I ran it later) since there were no SI properties for the same(my assumption based on this statement- Since in your case no smart identification properties were captured the Enable Smart Identification option is disabled for this object). However it wasn't being recognized with SI being disabled. My question was that if the object isn't being recognized without SI, why would it disable it in the first place as I believe SI properties were indeed added for the object?

Comment: I don't understand the problem, if the object isn't being identified you should try to fix its description. SI is a fallback mechanism, it's better for identification to work without it.